# how to calculate the median of words and character of large document or corpus python or nltk library , any way

Tags: python, count, nlp, nltk

function used to find but its seems result is not right please help me , i have calculated all data word count char count
def calculate_statistics (sentences):

```
                sentences = sentences.splitlines()
                word_counts = []
                char_counts []
                median_char_count = 0
                median_word_count = 0
                avg_word_count = 0
                avg_char_count = 0
                total_word_count = 0
                total_char_count = 0

            for sentence in sentences:
                words = sentence.split()
                word_count = len(words)
                char_count = sum(len(word) for word in words)
                word_counts.append(word_count)
                char_counts.append(char_count)
                total_word_count
                sum(word_counts)
                total_char_count = sum(char_counts)

                try:
                    avg_word_count = total_word_count / len(sentences)
                    avg_char_count= total_char_count/ len(sentences)
                    median_word_count = statistics.median (word_counts)
                    median_char_count = statistics.median (char_counts)
                except Exception as exception:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not adding to your total counts.
Additionally, it looks like you are calculating the averages in the for loop.
You can calculate them at the end.

From the code you have posted:

```
                sentences = sentences.splitlines()
                word_counts = []
                char_counts []
                median_char_count = 0
                median_word_count = 0
                avg_word_count = 0
                avg_char_count = 0
                total_word_count = 0
                total_char_count = 0

            for sentence in sentences:
                words = sentence.split()
                word_count = len(words)
                char_count = sum(len(word) for word in words)
                word_counts.append(word_count)
                char_counts.append(char_count)
                total_word_count += word_count # add to total
                total_char_count += char_count # add to total

            try: // moved entire try block outside of for loop
                avg_word_count = total_word_count / len(sentences)
                avg_char_count= total_char_count/ len(sentences)
                median_word_count = statistics.median (word_counts)
                median_char_count = statistics.median (char_counts)
            except Exception as exception:
                pass
```